# How do you read a gridview cell's set background color?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I need to change a gridview cell's color depending on the color of another gridview cell. How can I read the background color value of a specific cell? Say I'm trying to do it in the rowdatabound event...

```
Dim Color as String = e.Row.Cells(0)????
```

EDIT

I need to read the cell background color in the rowdatabound event when the background color was set in the markup like so:

CSS

```
.GridviewRowStyle
        {
            background-color: #E6B9B8;
            color: #000000;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

.SummaryGridViewStyle
        {
            width: 100%;
            border: 2px solid #000000;
        }
```

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSummary" runat="server" OnDataBound="grdSummary_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="grdSummary_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Gridlines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="SummaryGridViewStyle" >
    <RowStyle CssClass="GridviewRowStyle" />
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Get it using ...

```
e.Row.Cells(0).BackColor
```

Comment: OK that works if I've set the background color in the rowdatabound event. I'll edit the question as the original background color is set in the gridview markup.

Comment: You might try using e.Row.Style.Item("background-color") but not sure if that'll work.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to try and retrieve the color in data binding event before it's updated in rowdatabound. I'd give you an example for that as well but haven't really used data binding event for anything like that.